# P3DFFT++ installation on MacOS

Tags: c++, fft

Dear guys I need help to install P3DFFT++ on macOS.
The instructions just tells to modify the makefiles to set the proper compiler and path to fftw library.

I've done it and everything worked fine on Debian, but when I've used the same makefiles under macOS something went wrong.
The paths correctly points toward the fftw library in both systems and the compilers are the same (GNU compilers collection), the only different thing  is `ar` (I've also tried to use the GNU binutils under macOS but without success).

The errors I've got under macOS when I do `make all` are the followings:

```
`mpicxx test3D_r2c.o -o test3D_r2c_cpp -L.. -lp3dfft.3 -L/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 -lfftw3f  -lm 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/lib'
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(init.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(plan.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::~transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, float>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, double>::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<float>, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<float, std::complex<float> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
duplicate symbol p3dfft::transplan<double, std::complex<double> >::transplan() in:
    test3D_r2c.o
    ../libp3dfft.3.a(exec.o)
ld: 96 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [test3D] Error 1
make: *** [samples] Error 2`
```

What can I do to solve this kind of problems?
Thanks

Comment: The library name has **++** in it. Your file name has **cpp** in it... which stands for cee plus plus! The error messages have C++ syntax in them... Please tag the correct language from now on.

Comment: Do you really have a `/lib` directory ? The compiler doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: I've forgot to delete that row from the code, that path doesn't exist.
Anyway the library is present, is in `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: Since the library `libp3dfft.3.a` is generated using also `init.o, plan.o, exec.o` I tried to change the command `ar -v -r -u`, prescribed by the author, and replace it with `libtool -static -o` which, if I understood correctly, is the proper command on macOS to create static libraries. However nothing seems changed. I've the same 96 duplicates